How to trigger implicit pointer conversion inline in a C macro?
Context
I have some functions to support using a custom memory allocator in my library:
void *(allocate)(struct allocator *allocator, size_t size, size_t alignment);
void (deallocate)(struct allocator *allocator, void *pointer, size_t size, size_t alignment);

There's two things that I would still like to improve upon with this interface:

There is a need to write sizeof(type) and alignof(type) for every allocation and deallocation.
The type void * allows mistakenly using a pointer to a type with invalid size or alignment.

Both of these can be fixed with some simple macros:
#define allocate(allocator, type, count) \
    (type *)(allocate)(allocator, sizeof(type) * (count), alignof(type))

#define deallocate(allocator, pointer, type, count) \
    do { \
        type *typed_pointer = pointer; \
        (deallocate)(allocator, typed_pointer, sizeof(type) * (count), alignof(type)); \
    } while (0)

The macro takes care of calling sizeof(type) and alignof(type), and also performs a cast of the pointer to the given type so the compiler issues a warning when it is used as a different type.
Problem
deallocate does not have a return value, so we can implement it as a block with a variable to perform the implicit pointer cast. But for a function that does return a value, maybe reallocate, we cannot type check the pointer that is passed to the macro in the same way.
Is there any way to perform this "type checking" implicit cast inline inside of an expression, such that the macro can have a result?
EDIT: I would like to stick to standard C without any GNU or other extensions, if possible.

You mean like https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html?

Frame challenge: the deallocator shouldn't need to be told the size/alignment of the pointed-to memory.  It should keep track of that itself.  free doesn't need to be given that information.

The only "type" checking needed with reallocate() is the alignment.  Allocate in such a way that given a pointer from this (re)allocate() can recover the used alignment and then check that on reallocate().

@dbush Agree about lack of need for size/alignment yet passing them on deallocation allows for interesting/useful checks.

@CarlNorum Yeah, that would work, but I would like to stick to standard C without any extensions, if possible.

@dbush The caller knows the type of the pointer so it knows the size and alignment. Sharing this information with the allocator allows for efficient implementations that do not need to store the size and alignment themselves. C++ Allocator's deallocate function also takes in the size of the allocation. Also see https://nullprogram.com/blog/2023/12/17/


is not a problem than needs solving. Programming is all about typing. Those who have an aversion against typing ought to look for a different career or perhaps discover the wonders of copy/paste and code completion. The only problem that might need solving here is how to increase type safety.


You can use a compound literal, (type *) { pointer } as the argument to reallocate, and the compiler will do its usual checks for assignment to a pointer type. Per C 2018 6.5.2.5 2 and 6, the constraints and semantic rules for an initializer list apply to a compound literal, and per 6.7.9 11, the constraints and semantic rules for assignment apply to an initializer for a scalar, except that the type is taken to be unqualified.
Not all types can be handled this way, as appending *to a type does not necessarily yield a pointer to that type. For example, int [] would produce int [] *, which will not work. You already have that problem for the (type *) cast on allocate. The user could use a typedef for any type, though, and then pass the typedef name.

TIL compound literals are lvalues.

@DutChen18, That's the whole point. Otherwise, we could use constants.

@ikegami: Maybe 80% of the point. Maybe less. Compound literals are useful for constructing structure values, which is nice for assigning to structure variables. That may be the majority of what I have used them for in production code.

@Eric Postpischil, How is it better than an initializer (struct Foo foo = { ... };)?

@ikegami: That is an initializer. Sometimes I want to assign a value in the middle of the routine or return a (small) structure value. v = (vector) { x+2, y*3, z }; is nicer than v.x = x+2; v.y = y*3; v.z = z;.

Or just (type*){ pointer } which is equivalent. Initialization is done "as per assignment", so the same type compatibility check is performed either way.
